# How do I extract values from uniform list in R?

Tags: r, list, extract

For example, how do I get a vector of each and every person's age in the list `people` below:

```
> people = vector("list", 5)
> people[[1]] = c(name="Paul", age=23)
> people[[2]] = c(name="Peter", age=35)
> people[[3]] = c(name="Sam", age=20)
> people[[4]] = c(name="Lyle", age=31)
> people[[5]] = c(name="Fred", age=26)
> ages = ???
> ages
[1] 23 35 20 31 26
```

Is there an equivalent of a Python list comprehension or something to the same effect?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [sapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lapply.html):

```
> sapply(people, function(x){as.numeric(x[2])})
[1] 23 35 20 31 26
```

Comment: *facepalms* I totally disregarded the *apply stuff... Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Given the data structure you provided, I would use `sapply`:

```
sapply(people, function(x) x[2])

> sapply(people, function(x) x[2])
 age  age  age  age  age 
"23" "35" "20" "31" "26"
```

However, you'll notice that the results of this are character data.

```
> class(people[[1]])
[1] "character"
```

One approach would be to coerce to `as.numeric()` or `as.integer()` in the call to sapply.

Alternatively - if you have flexibility over how you store the data in the first place, it may make sense to store it as a list of `data.frame`s:

```
people = vector("list", 5)
people[[1]] = data.frame(name="Paul", age=23)
people[[2]] = data.frame(name="Peter", age=35)
...
```

If you are going to go that far, you may also want to consider a single data.frame for all of your data:

```
people2 <- data.frame(name = c("Paul", "Peter", "Sam", "Lyle", "Fred")
                      , age = c(23,35,20,31, 26))
```

There may be some other reason why you didn't consider this approach the first time around though...

Comment: Yes in this simple example a data frame is probably better. But the 'real' example is much more complicated so a list is a better fit. Thanks anyway

Comment: @c00kie - that's what I figured, but sometimes it's easy to overlook the seemingly obvious :)

Comment: +1 For the advice on R-ish, rather than Pythonic, data structures. Also, just because I think it's nifty: `sapply(people, "[", 2)`.

Comment: @joran, what does the "[" do in the sapply call? I've seen that notation before, but I can't really remember where...

Comment: @C00kie - `[` is used as an indexing tool. The help page is pretty useful and has some good info in it `?'['`. `[[` and `$` are discussed there as well.

Comment: So `[` is a function; type `?"["` for more. So you can apply the 'extract element function' to each element of `people`. `2` is passed as an additional argument to `[` via `...` in `sapply`.

Comment: +1 to @joran's method. Another option is `sapply(people,'[','age')`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ages <- sapply(1:length(people), function(i) as.numeric(people[[i]][[2]]))
ages
```

Output:

> [1] 23 35 20 31 26

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is pretty old, I'd like to share my approach to this. It is certainly possible to do with the `sapply` as 
[tflutre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597069/tflutre) suggested. But I find it more intuitive by using the `unlist` function:

```
> ages <- unlist(people, use.names = F)[seq(2, 2 * length(people), 2)]
> ages
[1] "23" "35" "20" "31" "26"
```

> NOTE the multiplication by **two** in `2 * length(people)`, there are two elements stored in the `poeple` list. This can be made more generic by writing `length(people[[1]]) * length(people)`

Here `unlist(people, use.names = F)` yields

```
[1] "Paul"  "23"    "Peter" "35"    "Sam"   "20"    "Lyle"  "31"    "Fred" 
[10] "26"
```

and we slice that by every other element using `seq` command.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the `apply`-family there's @Hadley's [`purrr` package](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) which offers the `map_`-functions for this kind of job.

(There's a few differences to the `apply`-family discussed for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101045/why-use-purrrmap-instead-of-lapply).)

OPs example:

```
people = vector("list", 5)
people[[1]] = c(name="Paul", age=23)
people[[2]] = c(name="Peter", age=35)
people[[3]] = c(name="Sam", age=20)
people[[4]] = c(name="Lyle", age=31)
people[[5]] = c(name="Fred", age=26)
```

The `sapply` approach:

```
ages_sapply <- sapply(people, function(x){as.numeric(x[2])})
print(ages_sapply)
[1] 23 35 20 31 26
```

And the `map` approach:

```
ages_map <- purrr::map_dbl(people, function(x){as.numeric(x[2])})
print(ages_map)
[1] 23 35 20 31 26
```

Of course they are identical:

```
identical(ages_sapply, ages_map)
[1] TRUE
```