# Why use purrr::map instead of lapply?

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

Is there any reason why I should use

```
map(<list-like-object>, function(x) <do stuff>)
```

instead of

```
lapply(<list-like-object>, function(x) <do stuff>)
```

the output should be the same and the benchmarks I made seem to show that `lapply` is slightly faster (it should be as `map` needs to evaluate all the non-standard-evaluation input).

So is there any reason why for such simple cases I should actually consider switching to `purrr::map`? I am not asking here about one's likes or dislikes about the syntax, other functionalities provided by purrr etc., but strictly about comparison of `purrr::map` with `lapply` assuming using the standard evaluation, i.e. `map(<list-like-object>, function(x) <do stuff>)`. Is there any advantage that `purrr::map` has in terms of performance, exception handling etc.? The comments below suggest that it does not, but maybe someone could elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: For simple use cases indeed, better stick with base R and avoid dependencies. If you already load the `tidyverse` though, you may benefit from the pipe `%>%` and anonymous functions `~ .x + 1` syntax

Comment: Plus, `purrr::map` provides a range of functions, such as `map_int`, `map_dbl`, `map_lgl`, and `map2` etc. that extend the functionality beyond `lapply` while keeping a consistent syntax.

Comment: I agree with both of you guys, all the functionalities mentioned by you are great and are *the* reason for me to use purrr, but I'm interested in the simple case and wonder if there is any advantage (maybe e.g. better exception handling?).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't read C code. Maybe the answer lies in the comparison between https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/b041e7897bc882037b7b5044a53e585c217a9b5a/src/map.c#L48 and https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2d080051873fbb0918e27fd716b0ffcbf5267990/src/main/apply.c#L34

Comment: This is pretty much a question of style. You should know what the base R functions do though, because all this tidyverse stuff is just a shell on top of it. At some point, that shell will break.

Comment: I only found one test in `purrr/tests/` comparing `map()` and `lapply()` outputs: `test_that("map forces arguments in same way as base R", {
  f_map <- map(1:2, function(i) function(x) x + i) ;
  f_base <- lapply(1:2, function(i) function(x) x + i) ;
  expect_equal(f_map[[1]](0), f_base[[1]](0)) ;
  expect_equal(f_map[[2]](0), f_base[[2]](0))
})` and interestingly, it fails when I copy-paste-and-run it. Does it have to do with evaluation rules? https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-map.R#L48

Comment: `~{}` shortcut lambda (with or without the `{}` seals the deal for me for plain `purrr::map()`. The type-enforcement of the `purrr::map_…()` are handy and less obtuse than `vapply()`. `purrr::map_df()` is a super expensive function but it also simplifies code. There's absolutely nothing wrong with sticking with base R `[lsv]apply()`, though.

Comment: @JanLauGe please look up `vapply`, `mapply` and friends. It's not because you don't know how to do it, that it doesn't exist in base R. Nothing against `purrr::map`, but it's JAF: Just Another Function.

Comment: @Aurèle You need the latest version of **purrr**. Seems to be a bug fix.

Comment: @F.Privé I updated to `0.2.2.9000`, now the test passes. Thank you

Comment: Admittedly, I wrote my answer before reading your post very carefully. My answer highlights stuff you probably already know, but in terms of pure performance, lapply is a bit faster. I think it's just about what you're more comfortable with...

Comment: Thank you for the question - kind of stuff I also looked at. I am using R since more than 10 years and definitively don't and won't use `purrr` stuff. My point is following: `tidyverse` is fabulous for analyses/ interactive/reports stuff, not for programming. If you are into having to use `lapply` or `map` then you are programming and may end up one day with creating a package. Then the less dependencies the best. Plus: I sometime see people using `map` with quite obscure syntax after. And now that I see performances testing: if you are used to `apply` family: stick to it.

Comment: Tim you wrote: "I am not asking here about one's likes or dislikes about the syntax, other functionalities provided by purrr etc., but strictly about comparison of purrr::map with lapply assuming using the standard evaluation" and the answer you accepted is the one that goes over  exactly what you said you didn't want people to go over.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli true, but this answer, as other answers, states that there is no difference and gives the most comprehensive review of the subject.

Comment: To Whom It May Concern: this question was put on hold as primarily opinion-based and re-opened already **four times in a row**. Not that it bothered me, but please notice that such voting pattern does not seem to lead anywhere...

Comment: @Tim you could rephrase the question as **"Can I safely replace any `lapply` call with a `map` call and expect my code not to break?"**. This removes the issue of some people interpreting your question as opinion-based and will still get you the right answers (if I got your question right)...

Comment: @jena thanks but it seems like the issues settled-up, while the shorter title is easier to read, so I'll keep with it.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

If the only function you're using from purrr is `map()`, then no, the
advantages are not substantial. As Rich Pauloo points out, the main
advantage of `map()` is the helpers which allow you to write compact
code for common special cases:

- `~ . + 1` is equivalent to `function(x) x + 1` (and `\(x) x + 1` in R-4.1 and newer)
- `list("x", 1)` is equivalent to `function(x) x[["x"]][[1]]`. These
  helpers are a bit more general than `[[` - see `?pluck` for details.
  For [data
  rectangling](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/data-rectangling), the
  `.default` argument is particularly helpful.

But most of the time you're not using a single `*apply()`/`map()`
function, you're using a bunch of them, and the advantage of purrr is
much greater consistency between the functions. For example:

- The first argument to `lapply()` is the data; the first argument to
  `mapply()` is the function. The first argument to all map functions
  is always the data.
- With `vapply()`, `sapply()`, and `mapply()` you can choose to
  suppress names on the output with `USE.NAMES = FALSE`; but
  `lapply()` doesn't have that argument.
- There's no consistent way to pass consistent arguments on to the
  mapper function. Most functions use `...` but `mapply()` uses
  `MoreArgs` (which you'd expect to be called `MORE.ARGS`), and
  `Map()`, `Filter()` and `Reduce()` expect you to create a new
  anonymous function. In map functions, constant argument always come
  after the function name.
- Almost every purrr function is type stable: you can predict the
  output type exclusively from the function name. This is not true for
  `sapply()` or `mapply()`. Yes, there is `vapply()`; but there's no
  equivalent for `mapply()`.

You may think that all of these minor distinctions are not important
(just as some people think that there's no advantage to stringr over
base R regular expressions), but in my experience they cause unnecessary
friction when programming (the differing argument orders always used to
trip me up), and they make functional programming techniques harder to
learn because as well as the big ideas, you also have to learn a bunch
of incidental details.

Purrr also fills in some handy map variants that are absent from base R:

- `modify()` preserves the type of the data using `[[<-` to modify "in
  place". In conjunction with the `_if` variant this allows for (IMO
  beautiful) code like `modify_if(df, is.factor, as.character)`
- `map2()` allows you to map simultaneously over `x` and `y`. This
  makes it easier to express ideas like
  `map2(models, datasets, predict)`
- `imap()` allows you to map simultaneously over `x` and its indices
  (either names or positions). This is makes it easy to (e.g) load all
  `csv` files in a directory, adding a `filename` column to each.

  ```
  dir("\\.csv$") %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map(read.csv) %>%
    imap(~ transform(.x, filename = .y))
  ```
- `walk()` returns its input invisibly; and is useful when you're
  calling a function for its side-effects (i.e. writing files to
  disk).

Not to mention the other helpers like `safely()` and `partial()`.

Personally, I find that when I use purrr, I can write functional code
with less friction and greater ease; it decreases the gap between
thinking up an idea and implementing it. But your mileage may vary;
there's no need to use purrr unless it actually helps you.

### Microbenchmarks

Yes, `map()` is slightly slower than `lapply()`. But the cost of using
`map()` or `lapply()` is driven by what you're mapping, not the overhead
of performing the loop. The microbenchmark below suggests that the cost
of `map()` compared to `lapply()` is around 40 ns per element, which
seems unlikely to materially impact most R code.

```
library(purrr)
n <- 1e4
x <- 1:n
f <- function(x) NULL

mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  lapply = lapply(x, f),
  map = map(x, f)
)
summary(mb, unit = "ns")$median / n
#> [1] 490.343 546.880
```

Comment: Did you mean to use transform() in that example? As in base R transform(), or am I missing something? transform() gives you filename as a factor, which generates warnings when you (naturally) want to bind rows together. mutate() gives me the character column of filenames I want. Is there a reason not to use it there?

Comment: Yes, better to use `mutate()`, I just wanted a simple example with no other deps.

Comment: Shouldn't type-specificity show up somewhere in this answer? `map_*` is what got me loading `purrr` in many scripts. It helped me with some 'control flow' aspects of my code (`stopifnot(is.data.frame(x))`).

Comment: ggplot and data.table are great, but do we really need a new package for every single function in R?

Comment: fwiw you can easily return a list while suppressing names in base R:  `sapply(1:10, function(x){x}, simplify=FALSE, USE.NAMES=FALSE)`

Answer (score 83):

### Comparing `purrr` and `lapply` boils down to **convenience** and **speed**.

---

### 1. `purrr::map` is syntactically more convenient than lapply

**extract second element of the list**

```
map(list, 2)
```

**which as @F. Privé pointed out, is the same as:**

```
map(list, function(x) x[[2]])
```

**with `lapply`**

```
lapply(list, 2) # doesn't work
```

**we need to pass an anonymous function...**

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[[2]])  # now it works
```

**...or as @RichScriven pointed out, we pass `[[` as an argument into `lapply`**

```
lapply(list, `[[`, 2)  # a bit more simple syntantically
```

So if find yourself applying functions to many lists using `lapply`, and tire of either defining a custom function or writing an anonymous function, convenience is one reason to favor `purrr`.

### 2. Type-specific map functions simply many lines of code

- `map_chr()`
- `map_lgl()`
- `map_int()`
- `map_dbl()`
- `map_df()`

Each of these type-specific map functions returns a vector, rather than the lists returned by `map()` and `lapply()`. If you're dealing with nested lists of vectors, you can use these type-specific map functions to pull out the vectors directly, and coerce vectors directly into int, dbl, chr vectors. The base R version would look something like `as.numeric(sapply(...))`, `as.character(sapply(...))`, etc.

The `map_<type>` functions also have the useful quality that if they cannot return an atomic vector of the indicated type, they fail. This is useful when defining strict control flow, where you want a function to  fail if it [somehow] generates the wrong object type.

### 3. Convenience aside, `lapply` is [slightly] faster than `map`

Using `purrr`'s convenience functions, as @F. Privé pointed out slows down processing a bit. Let's race each of the 4 cases I presented above.

```
# devtools::install_github("jennybc/repurrrsive")
library(repurrrsive)
library(purrr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

mbm <- microbenchmark(
  lapply       = lapply(got_chars[1:4], function(x) x[[2]]),
  lapply_2     = lapply(got_chars[1:4], `[[`, 2),
  map_shortcut = map(got_chars[1:4], 2),
  map          = map(got_chars[1:4], function(x) x[[2]]),
  times        = 100
)
autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

And the winner is....

```
lapply(list, `[[`, 2)
```

In sum, if raw speed is what you're after: **`base::lapply`** (although it's not that much faster)

For simple syntax and expressibility: **`purrr::map`**

---

[This excellent `purrr` tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls01_map-name-position-shortcuts.html) highlights the **convenience** of not having to explicitly write out anonymous functions when using `purrr`, and the benefits of type-specific `map` functions.

Comment: Note that if you use `function(x) x[[2]]` instead of just `2`, it would be less slow. All this extra time is due to checks that `lapply` doesn't do.

Comment: You don't "need" anonymous functions.  `[[` is a function.  You can do `lapply(list, "[[", 3)`.

Comment: @RichScriven that makes sense. That does simplify the syntax for using lapply over purrr.

Comment: `as.numeric(sapply(...))` is a weird thing to do. Use `vapply`: `vapply(..., FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))`. That's the base R way to return a vector from an apply function, and also enforces type (throws an error if your function doesn't return the correct one). This also results in better performance than `sapply`/`lapply` as the entire vector can be allocated at once. The only additional advantage of `map_type` is that it's a little bit more beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 55):

If we do not consider aspects of taste (otherwise this question should be closed) or syntax consistency, style etc, the answer is no, there’s no special reason to use `map` instead of `lapply` or other variants of the apply family, such as the stricter `vapply`.

*PS: To those people gratuitously downvoting, just remember the OP wrote:*

> I am not asking here about one's likes or dislikes about the syntax,
>   other functionalities provided by purrr etc., but strictly about
>   comparison of purrr::map with lapply assuming using the standard
>   evaluation

*If you do not consider syntax nor other functionalities of `purrr`, there's no special reason to use `map`. I use `purrr` myself and I'm fine with Hadley's answer, but it ironically goes over the very things the OP stated upfront he was not asking.*

Comment: I got here asking if there are some differences I should worry about between `lapply` and `map` or I can use them more or less interchangeably. You are the one who answered my question, thanks :) My use case is related to scripts from a colleague full of `map` where I want to use either `future.apply::future_lapply` (which I know) or `furrr::future_map` (which I don't know). Now I know I can safely replace one with the other, that's it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

### tl;dr

> I am not asking about one's likes or dislikes about syntax or **other functionalities** provided by purrr.

Choose the tool that matches your *use case*, and maximizes your *productivity*. For production code that prioritizes speed use `*apply`, for code that requires small memory footprint use `map`. Based on ergonomics, `map` is *likely* preferable for most users and most one-off tasks.

### Convenience

**update October 2021**
Since both the accepted answer and the 2nd most voted post mention syntax *convenience*:

R versions [4.1.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) and higher now support shorthand anonymous function `\(x)` and pipe `|>` syntax. To check your R version, use `version[['version.string']]`.

```
library(purrr)
library(repurrrsive)
lapply(got_chars[1:2], `[[`, 2) |>
  lapply(\(.) . + 1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1023
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1053
map(got_chars[1:2], 2) %>%
  map(~ . + 1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1023
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1053
```

Syntax for the `purrr` approach generally is shorter to type if your task involves more than 2 manipulations of list-like objects.

```
nchar(
"lapply(x, fun, y) |>
      lapply(\\(.) . + 1)")
#> [1] 45
nchar(
"library(purrr)
map(x, fun) %>%
  map(~ . + 1)")
#> [1] 45
```

Considering a person *might* write tens or hundreds of thousands of these calls in their career, this syntax length difference can equate to writing **1 or 2 novels** (av. novel 80 000 letters), given the code is typed. Further consider *your* code input speed (~65 words per minute?), *your* input accuracy (do you find that you often mistype certain syntax `(\"<` ?), *your* recall of function arguments, then you can make a fair comparison of *your* productivity using one style, or a combination of the two.

Another consideration might be your target audience. Personally I found explaining how `purrr::map` works harder than `lapply` precisely because of its concise syntax.

```
1 |>
  lapply(\(.z) .z + 1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2

1 %>%
  map(~ .z+ 1)
#> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object '.z' not found

but,
1 %>%
  map(~ .+ 1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
```

### Speed

Often when dealing with list-like objects, multiple operations are performed. A nuance to the discussion that the overhead of `purrr` is insignificant in most code - dealing with large lists and use cases.

```
got_large <- rep(got_chars, 1e4) # 300 000 elements, 1.3 GB in memory
bench::mark(
  base = {
    lapply(got_large, `[[`, 2) |>
      lapply(\(.) . * 1e5) |>
      lapply(\(.) . / 1e5) |>
      lapply(\(.) as.character(.))
  },
  purrr = {
    map(got_large, 2) %>%
      map(~ . * 1e5) %>%
      map(~ . / 1e5) %>%
      map(~ as.character(.))
  }, iterations = 100,
)[c(1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9)]

# A tibble: 2 x 7
  expression   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 base          1.19s     0.807    9.17MB   100   301      2.06m
2 purrr         2.67s     0.363    9.15MB   100   919      4.59m
```

This diverges the more actions are performed. If you are writing code that is used routinely by some users or packages depend on it, the speed might be a significant factor to consider in your choice between base R and purr. Notice `purrr` has a slightly lower memory footprint.

There is, however a counterargument: *If you want speed, go to a lower level language.*

Answer (score 2):

I think people hit most of the points here, but I want to mention that the speedup from the user's perspective in using `lapply()` becomes much more significant, particularly if you're not using R on Windows, when you upgrade to `mclapply()` (from the `parallel` package, which to my knowledge doesn't work on Windows and literally never will).  The `mclapply()` syntax is identical to `lapply()`, and so if you write your code using `lapply()` from the beginning, you won't need to change anything about your code aside from typing an "mc" at the beginning of the function call and providing it with a number of cores to use.  This may be important if you're using the `lapply()` to break a job up into parallelizable chunks; speedup factor compared with `lapply()` will be approximately the number of processor cores being used.  If you're using your code on the right server or cluster, that can easily turn hours into seconds.

Comment: JFYI, as `lapply()` has a counterpart `mclapply()`, `purrr::map()` and other `purrr` functions have a [`furrr`](https://furrr.futureverse.org/) counterpart to process data parallelly, e.g. `furrr::future_map()` (just add `future_` to the name of `purrr`'s functions).