# Write results paired t.test in csv

Tags: r, csv, t-test

I am performing a paired t test on data of multiple groups and would like to "export" this into a .csv file

Here's the data:

```
 table <- read.table(text=' group    M1      M2
 Group 1 0.5592884 0.5592884
 Group 1 0.3481799 0.3481799
 Group 1 0.2113786 0.2113786
 Group 1 0.2817871 0.2817871
 Group 2 0.2543952 0.2543952
 Group 2 0.2016288 0.2016288
 Group 2 0.2098503 0.2098503
 Group 2 0.1060097 0.1060097
 Group 3 0.2405704 0.2405704
 Group 3 0.3200119 0.3200119
 Group 3 0.2453895 0.2453895
 Group 3 1.3107510 1.3107510
 Group 4 0.8600338 0.8600338
 Group 4 0.5381423 0.5381423
 Group 4 0.7348685 0.7348685
 Group 4 0.2969512 0.2969512', header=TRUE)
```

as I don't want to compare M1 to M2 but the groups to each other, I perform the paired t.test as follows:

```
sig<-lapply(table[2:3], function(x) 
  pairwise.t.test(x, table$group,
                  p.adjust.method = "BH"))
```

However, as the result is a list, I cannot write is in a .csv file with this:

```
sink('test.csv')
cat('paired t results')
write.csv(sig)
sink()
```

I tried to work around by using `capture.output`, but this looses the separation

```
sig_output<-capture.output(print(sig))
```

is there a way to directly write `sig` into a csv file or a workouround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `print` after `sink`:

```
print(sig)
```

But note that the result is *not* a CSV file, contrary to what your code says. If you just want to save the p-value table, you could do something like the following:

```
save_p_values = function (test_data, filename) {
    write.csv(test_data$p.value, filename)
}

Map(save_p_values, sig, paste0(names(sig), '.csv'))
```

To get both tables in the same file, you need to add a column that distinguishes them; using ‹dplyr›:

```
sig_combined = sig %>%
    # Extract p-value tables
    map(`[[`, 'p.value') %>%
    # Convert matrix to data.frame so we can work with dplyr
    map(as.data.frame) %>%
    # Preserve rownames by saving them into column:
    map(tibble::rownames_to_column, 'Contrast') %>%
    # Add name of column that t-test was performed on
    map2(names(.), ~ mutate(.x, Col = .y)) %>%
    # Merge into one table
    bind_rows()

write.csv(sig_combined, 'results.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option works well for me! Any chance I can write the results for M1 and M2 in one file rather than two? Cheers :)

Comment: @KevinRoth Yes, you can set the `append = TRUE` argument in `write.csv`, and then just use the same filename. But in that case I’d probably just concatenate the tables first and write them afterwards, once.

Comment: @KevinRoth See updated answer. It’s a bit more effort. If you’re unfamiliar with the packages I’ve used, the commends should help. Briefly, [`purrr::map` is like `lapply` on steroids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47123420/1968), and dplyr is the future of structured table manipulation in R.

Comment: wow. thank you. This is far beyond my R capabilities, so for now, I'll just copy paste it and try to make it work for my actual dataset. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: works perfectly. Can I apply this solution to a table with more columns, as the input table could be anything from 1 to +10 columns (sorry for the inconvenience)

Comment: @KevinRoth I haven’t tested but yes, I believe it should work: my answer is general with respect to the number of columns that the test is applied over.

Comment: It does thank you! It didn't work first, but I realized this was my fault because I only performed the t.tests on 2 columns. Thanks again!