# How can I make multiple density plots from data inside a nested list

Tags: r, nested-lists, lattice, density-plot

I have a nested list containing 15 datasets (also lists), each of which has 3 columns but a variable number of rows (thousands each). The top of the last dataset looks like this in the console:

```
[[15]]
           Object.Number            Internal                      Membrane
1                0                 8.275335e+03                   2575.41042
2                2                 1.225267e+04                   5813.50000
3                3                 9.554725e+03                   2483.51172
```

I would like to make a 5x3 grid of density plots, created using the values in the 2nd column of each of 15 datasets.

I thought I could do this with `lapply (myFiles, densityplot(args))` but I can't find a way to reference the column within the arguments for `densityplot`.

Would be grateful for any insights on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `dplyr::bind_rows` with argument `.id` to row-bind all `data.frame`s into a single `data.frame`; then use `ggplot2` with `facet_wrap` to plot densities in a 3x5 grid layout.

Here is an example using the `mtcars` sample data:

```
# Create sample data
lst <- replicate(15, mtcars, simplify = F)

# Plot
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(lst, .id = "id") %>%
    mutate(id = factor(id, levels = as.character(1:15))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(mpg)) +
    geom_density() +
    facet_wrap(~ id, nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `purrr` you can use the shorthand notation using `~` and `.x`, for example:

```
library(purrr)
map(myFiles, ~ densityplot(.x[[2]]))
```

Comment: This is interesting. I don't know purrr at all, but I will certainly look into it. It seems like a very efficient way to do this.

Comment: Yes, the syntax using `.x` and `~` is short and convenient. It's however no different from defining the function inside `lapply` or `map`. So `map(myFiles, ~ densityplot(.x[[2]]))` is the same as `map(myFiles, function(x) densityplot(x[[2]]))`. The latter is in turn the equivalent of `lapply(myFiles, function(x) densityplot(x[[2]]))`. You can have a look at this comparison between `map` and `lapply` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101045/why-use-purrrmap-instead-of-lapply