# remove spaces and transform characters to lowers for whole dataframe

Tags: r

I am using this:

```
OriginalData <- data.frame(lapply(OriginalData, function(x) lower(trim(x))))
```

remove spaces and transform characters to lowers for a whole dataframe.

Unfortunately, entries like:

```
  Hello world
```

are not transformed to:

```
hello world
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
tolower(trimws("  Hello world"))
[1] "hello world"
```

for a `list` you had it right:

```
lapply(list("  Hello world", "  Hello world", "  Hello world"), function(x) tolower(trimws(x)))
```

Another solution with `purrr` package:

```
purrr::map(list("  Hello world", "  Hello world", "  Hello world"), 
       function(x) tolower(trimws(x)))
```

shorter call with `map`:

```
purrr::map(list("  Hello world", "  Hello world", "  Hello world"), ~tolower(trimws(.)))
```

Comment: why not use the shorthand notation `~` when using `purrr`?

Comment: a little less clear to me, but thanks for the suggestion, i'll include it. I'm just used to the other notation

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Why would `purrr::map` be faster than `lapply`? [REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101045/why-use-purrrmap-instead-of-lapply)

Comment: uh It seems I had it totally wrong, thank you for the reference. I can't remember where I read that it was faster.

Answer (score 1):

I possibly would have used `trimws` as well if RLave has not been faster.

```
OriginalData <- data.frame( A = I(c("Hehe huhu","  Hehe huhu  ", "  Hehe Huhu")), B = I(c("Funny Lol","  Funny Lol  ", "  Funny Lol")))

OriginalData[] <- lapply(OriginalData, function(x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "" , tolower(x)))
```