# Subset a nested list by a nested list of indices

Tags: r, list, indexing, nested, subset

I'm trying to subset this issue using R base. I have a list of names that I want to subset by severam nested lists of indices.
The list of names comes in as very compact and straightforward, the list of indices is nested an the indices may have leaps, ie, some numbers can be non-consecutive; each sublist starts the count from 1.

The index numbers may go until ~80, but they're always less than the vector of names, *ie.* it's always possible to use them to subset the element within the `List OfNames`.

Data are like this for the various `ListOfIndices_n`:

```
ListOfIndices_1<-list(
                       Chr1 = list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c(7,8,9,10), c(11,12)),
                       Chr2 = list(c(4,5), c(7,8,9,10)),
                       Chr3 = list(c(1,2,3), c(5,6,7,8,9), c(10,11), c(14,15,16))
                      )


ListOfIndices_2<-list(
                       Chr1 = list(c(1,2),c(5,6,7),c(10,11,12)),
                       Chr2 = list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5), c(9,10), c(13,14,15,16)),
                       Chr3 = list(c(1,2), c(5,6,7), c(10,11), c(15,16)),
                       Chr4 = list(c(2,3,4), c(5,6), c(8,9,10,11), c(13,14,15,16))
                      )
```

and like this for `ListOfNames`:

```
ListOfNames<-list(
                  Chr1 = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","A1","B2","C3","D4","E1","F2","G3","H4","I1"),
                  Chr2 = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a1","b2","c3","d4","e5","f6","g7","h8","i9","j10","k11","l12","m13","n14","o15","p16","q17","r18","s19","t20","u1","v2","w3","x4","y5","z6"),
                  Chr3 = c("aA","bB","cC","dD","eE","fF","gG","hH","iI","jJ","kK","lL","mM","nN","oO","pP","qQ","rR","sS","tT","uU","vV","wW","xX","yY","zZ")
                  Chr4 = c("aA1","bB2","cC3","dD4","eE5","fF6","gG7","hH8","iI9","jJ10","kK11","lL12","mM13","nN14","oO15","pP16","qQ17","rR18","sS19","tT20","uU21","vV22","wW23","xX24","yY25","zZ26")
)
```

What I want to get are several `ListOfIndicisedNames`, each the result of `ListOfNames` subsetted by a different `ListOfIndices_n`:

```
ListOfIndicisedNames_1<-list(
                           Chr1 = list(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),c("G","H","I","J"),c("K","L")),
                           Chr2 = list(c("d","e"), c("g","h","i","j")),
                           Chr3 = list(c("aA","bB","cC"), c("eE","fF","gG","hH","iI"), c("jJ","kK"),c("nN","oO","pP"))
)

ListOfIndicisedNames_2<-list(
                           Chr1 = list(c("A","B") c("E","F","G") c("J","K","L")),
                           Chr2 = list(c("a","b","c"), c("d","e"), c("i","h"), c("m","n","o","p"),
                           Chr3 = list(c("aA","bB"), c("eE","fF","gG"), c("iI","jJ"), c("oO","pP"))
                           Chr4 = list(c("bB2","cC3","dD4"), c("eE5","fF6"), c("hH8","iI9","jJ10","kK11"), c("mM13","nN14","oO15","pP16")
)
```

I've tried several flavours of `lapply()` and `sapply()`, though I didn't manage to get `do.call()` - I still find it very magical whenever I manage to make it work.

I think that another way could be gettig the result by a `for` loop with `i` and `j` for lists and sublists respectively, but every attempt has made R angry.

Could someone please help me in this maze?

Comment: I've updated my answer because I didn't like that it looked completely wrong. In general I would suggest that if your question has four answers, you shouldn't then edit it to a different question with different data. The suggestion on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066/drastic-question-revision) is that when this happens the question should be rolled back, but I didn't want to do that as then Soren's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78233421/12545041), which you accepted, would no longer answer the question. Next time just ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the list of names and list of indexes are the same lengths, these can be evenly iterated over using `mapply` and each sub-list can then be iterated over with `lapply`

```
mapply(function(indexes,names) {
  lapply(indexes,function(indexes,names) { names[indexes] },names=names)  
},indexes=ListOfIndices,ListOfNames)
```

Also, the example suggests that you want to assign names to the list?  Try using "=" instead of "<-" within the list definition:

```
ListOfIndices<-list(
                       Chr1 = list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c(7,8,9,10), c(11,12)),
                       Chr2 = list(c(4,5), c(7,8,9,10)),
                       Chr3 = list(c(1,2,3), c(5,6,7,8,9), c(10,11), c(14,15,16))
                      )
```

---

Following updates in response to additional discussions

(1) Assign names to the various lists (see comment above about using "=" instead of "<-"

(2) If different index variables are being passed in different circumstances, they can be unified around their common names (Chr1,Chr2, etc...)

(3) These can then be extracted from the list of names and list of indexes and their order will be preserved in the same order of the matched names, and also ensure their same lengths

For ListOfIndices_1:

```
which_names <- intersect(names(ListOfIndices_1),names(ListOfNames))
mapply(function(indexes,names) {
  lapply(indexes,function(indexes,names) { names[indexes] },names=names)  
},
indexes=ListOfIndices_1[which_names],
names=ListOfNames[which_names])
```

And for ListOfIndices2:

```
which_names <- intersect(names(ListOfIndices_2),names(ListOfNames))
mapply(function(indexes,names) {
  lapply(indexes,function(indexes,names) { names[indexes] },names=names)  
},
indexes=ListOfIndices_2[which_names],
names=ListOfNames[which_names])
```

Comment: The list of names is not always of the same length of the indices list(s - there are several I want to use to subset the ListOfNames). My apologies for providing only a single example of the ListOfIndices. Though, I'm about to try the approaches you suggested.

Comment: This could (potentially) change significantly the best answer, both in terms of mapply and also Map as suggested elsewhere, as these functions will sequentially iterate of the positions of ListOfIndeces and ListOfNames, eg, 1st entry of both, 2nd entry of both, etc.  If they're not the same length (or you don't want such pairwise matching), another solution might be better.  If so, you're invited to update the question with additional scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for precising it. I updated the question with an additional ListOfIndices and stated that there are several of them (four).

Comment: The updated example shows that `mapply()` and `Map()` are still viable as the lengths of the lists remain the same (3): `length(ListOfNames)==length(ListOfIndices_1)==length(ListOfIndices_2)==3` and with `lapply()` being called within `mapply()` its fine for there to be an arbitrary number of indexes to match against

Comment: Right, I mistook the update. Now is how they actually are.

Comment: I've provided an additional answer, but its predicated on correctly setting the names of the lists that are being generated -- and how to do that is to do "Chr1 = ... " etc, (instead of "Chr1 <- ...", which is not really correct syntax).

Comment: It works this way, thank you a lot! Exegi tibi monumentum aere perennius!

Answer (score 1):

#### Avoiding nested iteration

An approach to do this with out nesting `lapply()` or `map()` statements is to write a function which to subset a vector, `v`, by a list of vectors, `l`, without iteration. We can [`split()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html) `v` by the groups defined by the indices in `l`, and then [`unlist()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unlist.html) to extract the elements according to those indices. Finally, we can use [`rep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html) to repeat the indices as needed to ensure proper grouping. [`unname()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unname.html) simply strips the unnecessary names that are assigned by `split()`.

```r
subset_vector_by_list <- function(v, l) {
    split(
        v[unlist(l)],
        rep(seq_along(len <- lengths(l)), len),
    ) |> unname()
}
```

Then you can write a function to iterate over your list of indices:

```r
subset_list_by_list <- function(names_l, index_l) {
    lapply(names(index_l), \(nm, nm_list = names_l, l = index_l)
    subset_vector_by_list(nm_list[[nm]], l[[nm]]))
}
```

Then again you can just apply this to your relevant lists:

```r
subset_list_by_list(ListOfNames, ListOfIndices_1)
List of 3
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "G" "H" "I" "J"
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "K" "L"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "d" "e"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "g" "h" "i" "j"
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "aA" "bB" "cC"
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "eE" "fF" "gG" "hH" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "jJ" "kK"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "nN" "oO" "pP"
```

And

```r
subset_list_by_list(ListOfNames, ListOfIndices_2)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "E" "F" "G"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "J" "K" "L"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "d" "e"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "i" "j"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "m" "n" "o" "p"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "aA" "bB"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "eE" "fF" "gG"

[[3]][[3]]
[1] "jJ" "kK"

[[3]][[4]]
[1] "oO" "pP"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "bB2" "cC3" "dD4"

[[4]][[2]]
[1] "eE5" "fF6"

[[4]][[3]]
[1] "hH8"  "iI9"  "jJ10" "kK11"

[[4]][[4]]
[1] "mM13" "nN14" "oO15" "pP16"
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ListOfIndices<-list(
  Chr1 = list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c(7,8,9,10), c(11,12)),
  Chr2 = list(c(4,5), c(7,8,9,10)),
  Chr3 = list(c(1,2,3), c(5,6,7,8,9), c(10,11), c(14,15,16))
)

ListOfNames<-list(
  Chr1 = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","A1","B2","C3","D4","E1","F2","G3","H4","I1"),
  Chr2 = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a1","b2","c3","d4","e5","f6","g7","h8","i9","j10","k11","l12","m13","n14","o15","p16","q17","r18","s19","t20","u1","v2","w3","x4","y5","z6"),
  Chr3 = c("aA","bB","cC","dD","eE","fF","gG","hH","iI","jJ","kK","lL","mM","nN","oO","pP","qQ","rR","sS","tT","uU","vV","wW","xX","yY","zZ"))

new <- map2(ListOfIndices, ListOfNames, \(x, y) map(x, \(x) (y)[x]))
str(new)
#> List of 3
#>  $ Chr1:List of 3
#>   ..$ : chr [1:6] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
#>   ..$ : chr [1:4] "G" "H" "I" "J"
#>   ..$ : chr [1:2] "K" "L"
#>  $ Chr2:List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr [1:2] "d" "e"
#>   ..$ : chr [1:4] "g" "h" "i" "j"
#>  $ Chr3:List of 4
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "aA" "bB" "cC"
#>   ..$ : chr [1:5] "eE" "fF" "gG" "hH" ...
#>   ..$ : chr [1:2] "jJ" "kK"
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "nN" "oO" "pP"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from not just presenting a `tidyverse` alternative but explaining the advantage over a base R approach, if there is one. Hadley Wickham [wrote on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47123420/12545041), _If the only function you're using from `purrr` is `map()`, then no, the advantages are not substantial_. I'd think the same logic applies to `Map()` vs `map2()` as well. In fact the linked answer shows that `map()` is slightly slower than `lapply()`. So those are the cons - what are the pros?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, it is a little bit complicated but it works

```
ListOfIndices<-list(
                   Chr1 <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c(7,8,9,10), c(11,12)),
                   Chr2 <- list(c(4,5), c(7,8,9,10)),
                   Chr3 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(5,6,7,8,9), c(10,11), c(14,15,16))
                  )
ListOfNames<-list(
              Chr1 <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","A1","B2","C3","D4","E1","F2","G3","H4","I1"),
              Chr2 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a1","b2","c3","d4","e5","f6","g7","h8","i9","j10","k11","l12","m13","n14","o15","p16","q17","r18","s19","t20","u1","v2","w3","x4","y5","z6"),
              Chr3 <- 
c("aA","bB","cC","dD","eE","fF","gG","hH","iI","jJ","kK","lL","mM","nN","oO"," 
pP","qQ","rR","sS","tT","uU","vV","wW","xX","yY","zZ"))
ListOfIndicisedNames<-list(
                       Chr1 <- 
list(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),c("G","H","I","J"),c("K","L")),
                       Chr2 <- list(c("d","e"), c("g","h","i","j")),
                       Chr3 <- list(c("aA","bB","cC"), 
c("eE","fF","gG","hH","iI"), c("jJ","kK"),c("nN","oO","pP"))
)

# Checking the length of the lists to be matched
if (length(ListOfIndices) != length(ListOfIndicisedNames)) {
stop("Lengths of lists do not match!")
}

# Create an empty data frame
result_table <- data.frame()

# Matching indexes and names for each chromosome
for (i in seq_along(ListOfIndices)) {
# Get indexes and names for each chromosome
indexes <- unlist(ListOfIndices[[i]])
names <- unlist(ListOfIndicisedNames[[i]])

# Match names with indexes
matched_table <- data.frame(Indeks = indexes, Name = names)

# Merge to add to the result table
result_table <- rbind(result_table, matched_table)
}

print(result_table)
```